# Has Oswald Spengler ever been married or in a relationship with a woman and how did this influence his philosophical views?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, nietzsche, german-philosophy

I am asking this question in order to find out how a relationship or the absence thereof has influenced his philosophy and writings. He has been heavily influenced by Friedrich Nietzsche who has never been married and whose relationships with women have been very difficult throughout his life. Nevertheless, Nietzsche wrote about women and Spengler did too.

Maybe Spengler was gay or asexual. I don’t know. But maybe you do.

Comment: How exactly being gay, asexual or having relationships with women is supposed to influence Spengler's philosophy? Unless you have some tangible connection in mind this question is off-topic here.

Comment: @Conifold See, for example, the beginning of the chapter on PDF-page 798: https://ia800304.us.archive.org/12/items/Decline-Of-The-West-Oswald-Spengler/Decline_Of_The_West.pdf | Why does he think and argue that way?

Comment: Can't see how this question can be reworded in a way that would make it philosophically interesting. A psychological question could be asked if you specified Spengler's views on women and looked for a connexion between those views and his relationships, or rather non-relationships, with women. But it wouldn't belong on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the [website for the Institute for Oswald Spengler Studies](https://sites.google.com/site/spenglerinstitute/Biography), Spengler’s biography says he never married. He seems to have been a reclusive figure, even by comparison with other philosophers.